# How to literally slow time

Tags: time, relativity

Let's say there is this car in a bubble of some sort. I want to slow time for that car in the bubble, let's say, by half so if the car is going 40 mph, outside of the bubble, people see it as going 80 mph. How can this be done feasibly through the power of relativity? Or will there be technology in the near future to do so?

Please tell me if any part of this question is unclear. Also, before voting to close this question for any reason, please wait about 24 hours first for me to respond to any concerns about this question.

EDIT: I have noticed people voting for closing because is it unclear. What here is unclear about the question?

Comment: Physics deals with things that have been observed. Cars in time-slowing bubbles have, so far, not been observed.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the power of relativity'.

Comment: @CuriousOne this is a hypothetical situation... I just want to know if it is possible...

Comment: @Gert I just meant relativity principles ;)

Comment: @TanMath: parking it near a black hole or driving it near the speed of light makes times slow down for the driver and his car. Does that help?;-)

Comment: @Gert, ah... you took my answer while I was thinking it!.   The speed involved is too slow to perceptibly slow the clock, but you could put a super massive super dense material inside the bubble to slow the clock of the car.   Now the bubble would have to be some kind of gravity canceling bubble so that clocks outside the bubble aren't effected.   Oh but wait... The occupants and the car probably get crushed by the gravity required... I guess it needs some engineering work...

Comment: @scm "Bubble" suggests some discontinuous interface. A dense object gives you continuous tidal forces, no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Put the car on a treadmill. Put walls around the treadmill with images of trees and clouds, to create an outdoorsy impression, and printed on a loop of flexible fabric. Connect the fabric loops to the treadmill so the images move at the same rate as its upper surface. Put wheels on the underside of the treadmill, geared so their axles move forward at twice the speed shown on the car speedometer. Voilà!

Relativity is based on observations of reality. Physical theories do not exist to enable technologies. Tricky technologies often work by manipulating some free variable, something that can be adjusted without disturbing the user of the technology. Relativity, being a description of the geometry of reality, doesn't really give many knobs for adjustment.

That said, relativity is great for making precise measurements and finding connections between unlikely variables in space-time geometry. For example, in the coming decades we might get precise, miniature altimeters based on direct measurement of the gravity well separating the observer from a GPS satellite, via time dilation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your goal was to watch your twin die.

Assume you take care of your self (look after your health and safety) but want to really live longer. There are other options.

One is rockets. Get big rockets, take off and get up to a high speed, at some point turn around and fire your rockets to come back. You will have aged less. To age half as much you need to go at 87% of the speed of light, which would require at least an antimatter you amount of energy, that's around $270 billion worth of electricity at 12¢ per kWh. And you'll need more because you'll need to get the fuel for the return trip up to speed too. Plus even random hydrogen is going to slam into your really hard so you probably need some protective device too and then that needs to get up to speed.

Another option is gravity wells, this requires general relativity not just special relativity. That won't really get you a factor of two without using rockets as well. But since super deep gravity wells are far away anyway you might need then rockets anyway. To get up to a factor of two you can't really do not safely just orbiting or just floating inside a big sense shell. But if you fire rockets you can get close enough to a really huge star to get a factor as big as you want, but you'll need the rockets to escape. And there is a danger that if you don't engage the rockets in time that you will never be able to escape.

You won't feel older as far as you can tell its like your twin and everyone on earth was just aging faster.